# Charging a lead sealed battery

Tags: motor, battery-charging

I am making a pitching machine that that feeds balls through a pipe into two wheels. These wheels are powered by two motors, each running at 12v and 10a., and each on their own battery. I would like them to run for around 30 mins. I do not have an arduino or anything, and am just looking to take this out and use rechargeable batteries. Can someone help me figure out what the best type of battery to use would be for this situation? Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the required run time in hours. If your motors truly draw 10 A each and you want them to run for 2 hours then you need a 10 x 2 = 20 Ah battery for each. With a bit of safety margin you would be looking at 60 Ah rating. This is getting into car-battery territory.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. A couple things. First of all, each motor will be run on its own battery. Second, the motor should run for around only 30 mins. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As explained in my comments, 10 A (note capital for abbreviated units named after a person) x 0.5 h = 5 Ah capacity required per motor. Go for at least 7 Ah for some margin and decrease in capacity with age.

[image]

*Figure 1. Sealed lead-acid batteries.*

These have the advantages that they are robust, easily charged, can be mounted in any orientation, etc. You would have to purchase a charger to suit.

You may find suitable batteries in an old UPS, alarm panel, emergency lights, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need batteries that can sustain 12 V at 10 A for 30 minutes.

You need to convert that to a capacity figure to start with.  10 A for ½ hour is 5 amp-hours.  That's the charge the battery has to be able to deliver.  You want some margin, of course.  Depending on the battery technology, you may also not want to drain the battery fully each event.

In your case, a "12 V 10 Ah" battery might do it.

However, this is just a bit less than a small car battery.  I'd just get whatever 12 V car battery you can.  Even the smallest one will have more than 10 Ah capacity, but by using a car battery you tap into the high volume these are manufactured in.  That basically gets you more capacity for the same price.